# ConstraintLayout and ImageView render colors differently?

Tags: android

I have set same background and same color tint both for `ConstraintLayout` and `ImageView`, but the result kind of weird, the color a bit diffrent.

[image]

Comment: Can you also repoduce this behavior on a physical Android device? And could you also include the whole XML file in your post? There might be some other content overlaying the `ConstraintLayout` next to the `ImageView`.